# How to provide bucket path for nginx?

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, nginx-location

I am trying to add new webpages to the existing website. These webpages (.html) are stored on s3 bucket. When I update the config on nginx, I get the `The specified bucket does not exist` error

Below is the config code:

```
location ~ ^/biz/(.*)$ {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    set $bucket "womply-test-bucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com";
    proxy_pass http://$bucket/$1;
}
```

Error when I hit the url:

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
<Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message>
<BucketName>womply.com</BucketName>
```

The html pages are not located in `<BucketName>womply.com</BucketName>`
and not sure from where the nginx is sourcing the bucket name.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.